# SQL folder entity de-duplication process

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a databases that has tables to create a Folder/Entity type relationship. The important tables and columns are below.

### Table: folders

Columns: id(unique), name, created (date)

### Table: entity_map

Columns: folder_id, entity_id (Maps to a unique entity_id. Entities can be in more than 1 folder).

The issue is that there is no unique check on the folder.name column, so we have a bunch of folders with similar names (Which we do not want). I want to take the entities under all folders with similar names (lower(trim(name))) and put them under one of the folders already in existence (The folder with the oldest creation date will do).

Comment: what if you already have `/foo/BAR` and `/foo/bar`, which are "similar" by your definition, but actually contain completely different things?

Comment: @MarcB maybe OP wants a case insensitive 'filesystem'.

Comment: @MarcB I do want a case insensitive system. I said a folder/entity relationship in the sense that entities can go under folders, folders do not actually have a hierarchical structure. But for your example anything such as (Bar, BAR, baR) that has entities under it, I want to group them under the first 'bar' folder created and then remove the extra bar folders that no longer have entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
UPDATE entity_map, folders join 
(
 SELECT MIN(id) id ,(LOWER(TRIM(name))) name 
  FROM folders 
  GROUP BY (LOWER(TRIM(name)))
) AS f1 ON ((f1.id <> folders.id) AND (f1.name=folders.name))
SET entity_map.folder_id=f1.id
WHERE folder_id=folders.id;
```

This assumes that the folders.id is `AUTO_INCREMENT` and doesn't take the folder creation date into account. If you run the following in a single transaction with the above, it'll also remove the empty folders:

```
DELETE FROM folders 
 USING folders LEFT JOIN entity_map ON (folders.id=entity_map.folder_id) 
 WHERE entity_map.folder_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This approach needed a bit of alteration for some other external dependencies within my tables, but I have sorted it all out. Thank you for the help!